# using Ajax for logging in form in asp.net mvc 5

Tags: asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I am using ASP.NET MVC 5 and ASP.NET Identity for Authentication.
and i have an partial view (it's a modal) for log in form, i want to log in user without refreshing page (using Ajax) but i don't know how to use Ajax in Asp.Net MVC 5.
this is my partial view in : `Views/Shared/Partials/_LoginModal.cshtml`

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Login", "Account", new { ReturnUrl = ViewBag.ReturnUrl }, FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "", role = "form" }))
    {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
        <div class="control-group">

            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.UserName, new { @class = "control-label hidden shown-ie8", @for = "inputEmail" })
            <div class="controls">

                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.UserName, new { @class = "input-block-level", @id = "inputEmail", @placeholder = "User Name" })
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="control-group">
            <label class="control-label hidden shown-ie8" for="inputPassword">Password</label>
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Password, new { @class = "control-label hidden shown-ie8", @for = "inputPassword" })
            <div class="controls">

                @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.Password, new { @class = "input-block-level", @id = "inputPassword", @placeholder = "Password" })
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="control-group">
            <div class="controls">
                <label class="checkbox">
                    @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.RememberMe)
                    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.RememberMe)
                </label>
            </div>
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary input-block-level bold higher">
            Login
        </button>
    }
```

another thing that i want is : when user typed a wrong username/password i don't want to redirect to `/Account/LogIn` i want to show error message in my log in form.

Answer (score 0):

Include an id for submit button:

```
<button type="submit" id="submitButton" ... >
```

Use jquery ajax to send data:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#submitButton").click(function (event) {
            $.ajax(
            {
                url: $("form").attr("action"),
                data: $("form").serialize(),
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (data) {
                    if (data == 'your error code or message')
                        alert('Wrong login/password');
                }
            });

            // Avoid to post 2 times.
            event.preventDefault();
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you bro, but what is @Ajax.BeginingForm ? url: $("form").attr("action") should i replace my action name with action?